# How can I extract dependency triple from a parse tree

Tags: nlp

How can I extract dependency triple from a parse tree generated by an OpenNLP parser for arabic texts?

for example, the dependency triples in “I have a brown dog” consist of:
  (have subj I), (have obj dog), (dog adj-mod brown),(dog det a)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Arabic, but I didn't think OpenNLP Parser produced dependencies. You would have to write something to work with the parses. 
In English, the parse will look something like this:

```
(TOP (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VB have) (NP (NP (DT a) (JJ brown) (NN dog))) (. .))
```

It's at least conceivable to produce triples like you describe from this, but it's not exactly straightforward. Have you tried  [Stanford Arabic Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/arabic.shtml)?